# Why cannot I not access the data in this array ForEach loop? SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, xcode, loops, foreach, swiftui

I am having some difficulty with this issue. The ForEach loop is not allowing me to use the data in the 'weather' object for some reason. I have done this earlier and I could put weather.main.rTemp and get the value from the object but now I receive an error saying this does not exist, however nothing has changed? the only option it suggests in Xcode autofill is weather.self (which doesn't work or help either)

I am lost with this please help me.

My main view:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct MainForecastView: View {

    @ObservedObject var networkingManager: NetworkingManager

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            // Text("Weather Forecast")
              //  .font(.headline)
               // .padding(.bottom, 25.0)

            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Today")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                    Text(self.getDateToday())
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                Image(systemName: "sun.min.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("12°")
                        .font(.system(size:48))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    Text("Sydney, AU")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            HStack {
                Text("Upcoming Forecast")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .padding(.top)
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.leading, 10.0)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(networkingManager.weatherList, id: \.dt) { weather in
                        CardView(forecastTime: "12PM", forecastTemp: self.networkingManager.weatherList[0].main.rTemp)

                    }.padding(.vertical)
                }
            })
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Chance of Showers")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.leading, 10.0)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud.rain.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 28))
                    Text("Low Chance")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()
                }.padding(.leading, 10.0)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear(){
            self.networkingManager.load()
        }
        .blur(radius: 0)
        .padding()
    }
    func getDateToday() -> String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
        let dateToday = df.string(from: Date())
        return dateToday
    }
}

struct MainForecastView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainForecastView(networkingManager: NetworkingManager())
    }
}
```

Then to my Networking Manager class

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class NetworkingManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var inputCity = "Sydney"
    @Published var weatherList = [WeatherInfoList]()
    var weatherCity = CityInformation(name: "Sydney", country: "AU")

    func load() {
        let apiKey = "ced81d2f91438e7897c4443c4567c205"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=\(inputCity)&units=metric&APPID=\(apiKey)") else {
            return
        }
        print("City is: \(inputCity)")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let weatherInfo = try! JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherAPIResponse.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.weatherCity = weatherInfo.city
                self.weatherList = weatherInfo.list
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Finally my Data model structure from the API

```
    import Foundation

struct WeatherAPIResponse: Decodable {
    var list: [WeatherInfoList]
    var city: CityInformation
}
struct CityInformation: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var country: String
}
struct WeatherInfoList: Decodable {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    var dt: Int
    var main: WeatherMain
    var dtTxt: String
    var date: String {
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEE hh:mm a"
        let cDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dt))
        return formatter.string(from: cDate)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dt
        case main
        case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
    }
}

struct WeatherMain: Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
    let tempKf: Double

    var rTemp: Int {
        return Int(temp)
    }
    var rTempMax: Int {
        return Int(tempMax)
    }
    var rTempMin: Int {
        return Int(tempMin)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure
        case seaLevel = "sea_level"
        case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
        case humidity
        case tempKf = "temp_kf"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just tried your code (i had to change it a little bit, but it is compilable).

Try this:

unfortunately you did not show us your cardView implementation...maybe the problem is there?

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var networkingManager: NetworkingManager

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            // Text("Weather Forecast")
              //  .font(.headline)
               // .padding(.bottom, 25.0)

            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Today")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                    Text(self.getDateToday())
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                Image(systemName: "sun.min.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("12°")
                        .font(.system(size:48))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    Text("Sydney, AU")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            HStack {
                Text("Upcoming Forecast")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .padding(.top)
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.leading, 10.0)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(networkingManager.weatherList, id: \.dt) { weather in
           //             CardView(forecastTime: "12PM", forecastTemp: self.networkingManager.weatherList[0].main.rTemp)
                        Text(weather.date)
                    }.padding(.vertical)
                }
            })
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Chance of Showers")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.leading, 10.0)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud.rain.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 28))
                    Text("Low Chance")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()
                }.padding(.leading, 10.0)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear(){
            self.networkingManager.load()
        }
        .blur(radius: 0)
        .padding()
    }
    func getDateToday() -> String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
        let dateToday = df.string(from: Date())
        return dateToday
    }
}

struct MainForecastView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(networkingManager: NetworkingManager())
    }
}


class NetworkingManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var inputCity = "Sydney"
    @Published var weatherList = [WeatherInfoList]()
    var weatherCity = CityInformation(name: "Sydney", country: "AU")

    func load() {
        let apiKey = "ced81d2f91438e7897c4443c4567c205"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=\(inputCity)&units=metric&APPID=\(apiKey)") else {
            return
        }
        print("City is: \(inputCity)")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let weatherInfo = try! JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherAPIResponse.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.weatherCity = weatherInfo.city
                self.weatherList = weatherInfo.list
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct WeatherAPIResponse: Decodable {
    var list: [WeatherInfoList]
    var city: CityInformation
}
struct CityInformation: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var country: String
}
struct WeatherInfoList: Decodable {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    var dt: Int
    var main: WeatherMain
    var dtTxt: String
    var date: String {
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEE hh:mm a"
        let cDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dt))
        return formatter.string(from: cDate)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dt
        case main
        case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
    }
}

struct WeatherMain: Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
    let tempKf: Double

    var rTemp: Int {
        return Int(temp)
    }
    var rTempMax: Int {
        return Int(tempMax)
    }
    var rTempMin: Int {
        return Int(tempMin)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure
        case seaLevel = "sea_level"
        case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
        case humidity
        case tempKf = "temp_kf"
    }

}
```